# iPhone UIPickerView not loading values

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview

I attempted to build a basic application prototype (mimic real application flow).  I created one view controller class and linked the UIPickerView to the .h file. Wrote the logic but still nothing is reflecting in the picker.

Am I missing something? Here you go with the code:

```
@implementation SelectCountryForViewAdsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1; // For one column
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.colorArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.colorArray objectAtIndex:row]; // If it's a string
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.colorArray  = [[NSArray alloc]         initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Green",@"Orange",@"Purple",@"Red",@"Yellow" , nil];

}
```

and in the .h file:

```
@interface SelectCountryForViewAdsViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *countrySelector;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *colorArray;

@end
```

Any help is appreciated. I am a beginner in iOS devs.

Comment: Have you given delegate and datasource from xib to UIPicker view?

Comment: nope I didn't. Please clarify on how to do so...it will add value for future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below image you need to right click on UIPicker view and connect it File owner.

[image]

Please check below link for more detail

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/09/uipickerview-tutorial.html (More helpful)

http://www.developersalmanac.com/uipickerview-tutorial/

Comment: That did it! added the lines from the example in second link and it worked. Thanks impossible.

Comment: will do so in 3 minutes as it is not allowing me now.

Answer (score 1):

```
[countrySelector setDelegate:self];
 [countrySelector setDataSource:self];
```

//Use this code in Viewdidload method

Answer (score 1):

Add `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` in your interface file.

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.countrySelector.delegate = self;
self.countrySelector.dataSource = self;
```

You can set the `delegate` and `dataSource` directly from the `xib` file. But don't forget to mention them in the interface file.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UILabel *lblRow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView bounds].size.width, 44.0f)];
    [lblRow setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor strawberryColor]];
    [lblRow setText:self.colorArray[row]];
    [lblRow setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:18]];
    [lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return lblRow;
}
```